# How to get all the required details from a single user in dialogflow bot and to get that stored in firestore under a single userId

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, chatbot, dialogflow-es

My sample index.js code for saving name alone:

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);
exports.dialogflowFirebaseFulfillment = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {
let action = request.body.result.action;
var Name = request.body.result.parameters.Name;
let query = request.body.result.resolvedQuery;
const parameters = request.body.result.parameters; 
const inputContexts = request.body.result.contexts; 
if(action === 'save.name' || inputContexts == 'welcome'){
        admin.firestore().collection('users').add({
        name: Name
        }).then(ref => {
        console.log('Added new user');
       });    
    } 
 });
```

Right now, I have implemented saving name separately and saving other details separately, but the problem is everything is gets stored in separate userId's in firestore,
 **I want all details of single user to be stored in single userId**

That is to say, if all users were going to be asked the same questions, I could handle them all in a single intent. But I have to get different information from each user, so I have to ask multiple questions and store all the answers as I get them for the same user. How can I do this?

I am using api v1 bot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Broadly speaking, what you need to do is update the doc stored in Firestore for each Intent that delivers data to you. You can do this with `docRef.update()`.

The tricky bit is that when you create the document, you'll need to save a way to get the document back later to update it. This requires two things:

1. You need to either create the document with a known id, or get the id assigned by the system.
2. You then save this in a Dialogflow Context and get it out of the Context the next time you handle an Intent.

We'll use the user id for a few things, so we can declare it up top.

```
var userId; // We'll use this for a few things
```

When you create the document, the `ref` that is returned has a field `id` that contains the id of the added document.

```
admin.firestore().collection('users').add({
  name: Name
}).then(ref => {
  userId = ref.id;
  console.log('Added new user with id '+userId);
});
```

You don't show how you're sending the prompt back to the user, but I get the feeling you're using JSON. If so, you'll set or update an output context with something like this:

```
var outputContext = [
  {
    name: "user_information",
    lifespan: 5,
    parameters: {
      id: userId
    }
  }
];

responseObject = {
   // ...
   outputContext: outputContext
};
```

When the next Intent information comes in to handle, you'll need to get the user id. I've broken it out into a function (not the tidiest or most efficient, but illustrates generally how you have to handle it):

```
var getIdFromRequest = function( request ){
  var id;
  var contexts = request.body.result.contexts;
  for( var co=0; co<contexts.length; co++ ){
    var context = contexts[co];
    if( context.name === 'user_information' ){
      id = context.parameters.id;
    }
  }
  return id;
}
```

In your Intent handling, you'd get the id with

```
userId = getIdFromRequest( request );
```

When we go to add data, we'll create an object, add parameters to it, and then update the document with this new object. (This code isn't the most efficient way, but logically it would be something like this)

```
var updateObj = {};
if( parameters.color ){
  updateObj.color = parameters.color;
}
if( parameters.pet ){
  updateObj.pet = parameters.pet;
}
if( parameters.age ){
  updateObj.age = parameters.age;
}

admin.firestore().collection('users').doc(userId).update( updateObj )
  .then( ref => {
    console.log('User updated');
  })
  .catch( err => {
    console.error.( 'Something is wrong', err );
  };
```

Comment: Thank you..Great idea! Is it necessary to update the output context for all the indents, Because I have already defined separate output and input contexts for all the indents, and I am responding to the user based on the text responses in dialogflow, Based on user reply I will move on to next indent using contexts!

Comment: You can send more than one context each time and you don't need to specify them as input contexts - a context will be available for as long as its lifetime is above 0 and will decrease this lifetime for each call. So you can either set it with a very large lifetime at the beginning, or just send a replacement one each time. Either way works.

Comment: And I'm glad this will work for you! If you find the answer help, accepting and/or upvoting it is always appreciated.

Comment: db.collection('users').doc(this.username).collection('booksList').add({
  password: this.password,
  name: this.name,
  rollno: this.rollno
}) Will this type of queries work in this case

Comment: Without knowing details of how you're trying to structure things, it should. If you're having issues with that particular update, asking it as a new StackOverflow question with as much detail about code and problems might be best.